# How to react to the retraction of a conference acceptance?

Tags: conference, withdraw

One of my papers was accepted at a regional conference. The conference organizers wanted the presenters to register to the conference much more in advance than common. I wrote the organization chair and repeatedly expressed my sincerest intention to attend the conference. But with the conference being so far away and the registration being actually quite hefty, I asked the organizer about the cancellation policy, since there was none listed on their website. I also have a family situation that makes it hard for me to plan so far in advance, but for my career it would be important to present at conferences like this one.
As a response, I received an email in which the conference organization chair basically retracted my conference acceptance. I am a little bit shocked, since I really wanted to attend the conference and thought I had made that clear in my email.

What would be the professional way to react? Do I just accept the conference chair's decision to retract my acceptance and walk away? Or do I email the chair, explain that I really want to attend and submit my registration fee?

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question. Did you actually want to attend the conference or not?

Comment: Speaking for CS, when one paper is accepted in one conference, (a) you must pay the registration fee (usually shortly after submitting the camera ready version) and (b) go to the conference to present your paper. As I understand, you have not done (a). Without (a) the whole conference system falls apart, because the organizers cannot predict if you will show up or not. Emails are free but do not guarantee you will be there.

Comment: @Alexandros: I had not paid the registration yet, but the registration period had not ended yet, either.

Answer (score 5):

If you're willing to register by the stated deadline (and that deadline hasn't already passed), then you could call the conference chair and explain that you would still like to present at the conference and that you're willing to register before the deadline.  This is not the kind of problem that you'd want to resolve through emails.